# backstepping control of third order non linear system.

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have the following question from an exercise set of the course "Control of Non Linear Mechanical Systems."

It involves so called integrator backstepping. And I've got a vague idea from a website how it must be done but I'm looking for a simple step by step guide for dummies.

The question is as follows:
Consider the third order system:

$\dot{x}_1 = x_2+x_1^2-x_1^3$

$\dot{x}_2 = x_{3}$

$\dot{x}_3 = u$

Check that after one step of backstepping we can globally stabilize the second order system:

$\dot{x}_1 = x_2+x_1^2-x_1^3$

$\dot{x}_2 = x_3$

With $x_3$ as an input by the control $x_3 = -2x_1(x_2+x_1^2-x_1^3)-x_2-x_1^2-x_1$ Hint: Use the Lyapunov function $V(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}(x_2+x_1^2)^2$. Using this result, design a controller that stabilizes the third order system.

What I do know:

I know that $x_2$ must cancel the non-linear quadratic term in $\dot{x}_1$, so $x_2 = -x_1^2$
And $x_3$ = $\phi(x_1,x_2)$ and $V(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2$

The more I try it, the more confused I get. There also has to be a transformation to $z$ coordinates for some reason, but that's not entirely clear to me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anybody looking for a solution to this problem can check out *example 14.9* on page 593 of *Non Linear Systems* by Khalil. ($3^{rd}$edition).

Which is exactly the same problem as posted here.